# OLS Estimator for linear regression model is a linear estimator

Tags: probability, regression, least-squares

Proofs for the Gauss-Markov Theorem often assume without showing that the OLS $\hat{\beta}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$ is linear, that is that for $y_1,y_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n $ $$\hat{\beta}(y_1+y_2)=\hat{\beta}(y_1)+\hat{\beta}(y_2)$$
Is this just as trivial as putting $$\hat{\beta}(y_1+y_2)= (X^TX)^{-1}X^T(y_1+y_2)=...$$
I don't think so, I think there is more to it that I can't figure out and would appreciate your help.

Comment: Nope, it's just as trivial as that. Just call $(X^T X)^{-1} X^T$, which is independent of $Y$, a matrix $M$, and then with the clutter gone its easier to see that $\hat \beta = M Y$ is linear.

Comment: Thank you very much. So $\hat{\beta}(y_1+y_2)= (X^TX)^{-1}X^T(y_1+y_2)=...$ is correct and not $\hat{\beta}(y_1+y_2)= (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY(y_1+y_2)=...$ right? I am a bit confused about the $\hat{\beta}(y_1)$ notation.